# Plural ending -im with proper names

Tags: hebrew, bible-names, name

Muslim apologists claim that the word mahmadim from Song of Solomon 5:16 is name of Muhammad, although it is just a Hebrew word meaning precious and pleasant and it comes in other verses too.

I have noticed that singular names like David, Shaul, and Mosheh are never changed to plural forms like Davidim, Moshehim, and Shaulim in the Bible. According to [BibleHub website](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/1732.htm), "David" is mentioned more than 1000 times and there is no single "Davidim" among them.
And there are plural names, like Huppim, Ephraim, and Hushim that are never changed to the singular form, as -im is part of the name.

So does it mean that since the name Muhammad doesn't have originally -im ending, then it can't be changed to Muhammadim, like David, Shaul, and Mosheh can't?

Song of Solomon 5:16

> His mouth is most sweet, and he is altogether **desirable**
> [מַחֲּמַדִּ֑ים "mahamadim]. This is my beloved and this is my friend,
> O daughters of Jerusalem.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: The plural endings "im" on names almost often signify the nation of people that came from the individual.  However some names are simply plural or dual such as shamyim.  Each has to be considered individually.

Comment: While the word for "desirable / precious [thing]" (מַחְמָד / *maḥmād*)  has the corresponding letters of the later name Mohammed, such a reading ignores the plain sense of the text and anachronistically reads this name into the text. The plural here for מַחֲמַדִּים (*makhmaddim*) probably implies intensity (i.e., "very desirable").

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B8%A4-M-D

Comment: What inplies that it is not a proper name, is saying we-kul-low before, it means he is altogether, all of him. Saying "all of him is Muhammad" doesn't make sense because no one can be half of Muhammad or third of him etc. While saying "all of him is desirable" does make sense

Comment: please provide a source from a specific Muslim apologist arguing what you claim.

Comment: You can search yourself, Ahmad Didat, Muhammad in song of songs

Comment: "*You can search yourself, Ahmad Didat, Muhammad in song of songs*". I believe @DanFefferman meant that you should provide us with a link that takes us directly to the apologist's thesis. The search terms you mention don't lead to a source, let alone a specific one, that supports the assertion.

Comment: @user62150 - you can see a very complete answer to this passage here:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/78642/47775 - 'im' is added as respect as Elohim - a name should never be changed regardless of the language translation - Mr Black is Mr Black even if his colour is actually white.

Comment: ok, but why isn't "im" added to David, Mosheh, Shaul etc? They didn't respect them? "Mr Black" is incorrect analogy because you know it is a name because of "Mr". If you say just "black" you can't tell it is a name. Also the word "altogether" suggests that machamaddim is not name

Comment: @user62150 - good Q, response from a Muslim colleague - probably because he was the last / final and most esteemed prophet – albeit that’s an opinion.  Name - The point I was making is that a name should not be changed in any way; YHWH – Jehovah, Yeshua or Asa – Jesus etc… shouldn’t happen, the west like the ‘J’  which is not in Hebrew.  If you read 5:10-16 its clearly talking about a person

Comment: There is a no reason to think that it is a name. The word מחמד is a usual hebrew word that is mentioned 11 times in the Bible, not including song of songs, ano none of them is used as a name

Comment: @user62150 - מחמד (allowed) not sure what that’s got to do with it - the link above was the Q - the A I was referring to was https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/80248/47775 - I presume you read that!

Comment: מחמד (https://biblehub.com/hebrew/4261.htm) means desirable, pleasant. מחמדים is intensive plural like mamtaqqim (most sweet) from the same verse

Comment: @user62150 - that’s fine - but all names have other meanings - Hosea means salvation etc... the link Answers the point you raise - maybe post on that Q your A or what you believe is inaccurate

Comment: @user62150 - I have asked a Q related to this passage on the Jewish stack exchange, should provide some good info - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/140678/34634

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how can they be serious?  The verse would then read:

> His mouth is most sweet, and he is altogether Mohammeds.

What is expected after "altogether" is an adjective, both grammatically and because of the mild parallelism.  But "Mohammed"is not an adjective, plus given the verb of being it can't be plural.  On that basis alone "Mohammed" is not a possible reading.

As for names never being plural, that's true with the exception of someone's name being used for a people or tribe, but then it's not the person's name any longer.  There are nouns which are plural in form but singular in meaning, but not names.